# How to read from STDIN_FILENO with blocking I/O

Tags: linux, posix, glibc

How can I read from STDIN_FILENO with blocking, I/O, i.e. I won't get -1 if there isn't any data. Seems that I have to clone the handle somehow. But I don't know why.

Comment: That is the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you read from stdin with

```
read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, COUNT);
```

it will block until COUNT bytes are read.

Comment: It does not block until COUNT bytes are ready.  `fread` will do that, but `read` will only block until at least one byte is available.

Comment: The problem here is that STDIN_FILENO is line-buffered and read returns only if a sequence ends with a newline and returns up to COUNT characters, maybe leaving further charaters in the kernel's buffer. How do I change the mode from line-buffered to an unbound character-sequence ? Is there sth. like Windows' SetConsoleMode() / ~ENABLE_LINE_INPUT ?

Comment: @BonitaMontero That is incorrect; stdin is not line-buffered.  Your terminal may buffer lines and not send any data until a newline is entered, but that is a completely different topic.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, thanks for the correction, I should have said that "*On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates
       end of file), and the file position is advanced by this number.
       It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of
       bytes requested;*"

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that also makes the console temporarily non-canonical:

```
if( isatty( STDIN_FILENO ) )
{
    termios tiosSave, tiosNew;
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &tiosSave );
    tiosNew = tiosSave;
    tiosNew.c_lflag &= ~(tcflag_t)(ICANON | ECHO);
    tiosNew.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tiosNew.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &tiosNew );
    char ch;
    (void)read( STDIN_FILENO, &ch, 1 );
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &tiosSave );
}
```